# Evenly divide X items N ways

Tags: algorithm

I was wondering if someone could provide insight to an algorithm that would divide a given number of items, say x, into n different groups.

So for example.

| # Items | # Groups | Groupings |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 | Group1 is 3, Group2 is 2 |
| 5 | 3 | Group1 is 2, Group2 is 2, Group3 is 1 |
| 8 | 7 | Group1 is 2, Groups2-7 is 1 |
| 10 | 2 | Group1 is 5, Group2 is 5 |

There is really no limit to what the values of x number of items and n number of groups could be. One could be thousands and the other could be 87 for example.

- x is greater than or equal to n
- number of items is x
- Number of groups is n
- Sum of all group values is x

Comment: typo, corrected thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for some time and could not find anything. After posting, I searched again and immediately found what I was looking for (lol).

```html
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;; 
  
// Function that prints  
// the required sequence 
void split(int x, int n) 
{ 
  
// If we cannot split the  
// number into exactly 'N' parts 
if(x < n) 
cout<<"-1"<<" "; 
  
          
  
    // If x % n == 0 then the minimum  
    // difference is 0 and all  
    // numbers are x / n 
    else if (x % n == 0) 
    { 
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) 
        cout<<(x/n)<<" "; 
    } 
    else
    { 
  
        // upto n-(x % n) the values  
        // will be x / n  
        // after that the values  
        // will be x / n + 1 
        int zp = n - (x % n); 
        int pp = x/n; 
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)  
        { 
  
            if(i>= zp) 
            cout<<(pp + 1)<<" "; 
            else
            cout<<pp<<" "; 
        } 
    } 
} 
      
// Driver code 
int main() 
{  
          
int x = 5; 
int n = 3; 
split(x, n); 
  
}
```

Source: Geeks for Geeks : Split the number into N parts such that difference between the smallest and the largest part is minimum.
Link : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-the-number-into-n-parts-such-that-difference-between-the-smallest-and-the-largest-part-is-minimum/